# Eclipse Neon Error: Nullpointerexception when adding Lucene 6.6 dependencies to build path (org.eclipse.jface)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lucene, dependencies

I'm developing with lucene 6.6 in eclipse neon 3 and when i add different lucene jars (e.g. `lucene-6.6.0-core.jar`) to the build path of my project i get a popup with a nullpointerexception. It then happens everytime i select the project or content within it. Confusingly my error log is not mentioning lucene but a plugin called "org.eclipse.jface":

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2017-07-17 10:29:55.989 !MESSAGE Problems
>   occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface". !STACK
>   0 java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.web.WebAppProvider.getImage(WebAppProvider.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25LabelProvider.getImage(Web25LabelProvider.java:47)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:199)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:57)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:195)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:121)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:949)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:118)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1029)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:474)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2170)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:843)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createAddedElements(AbstractTreeViewer.java:416)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalAdd(AbstractTreeViewer.java:285)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalAdd(TreeViewer.java:615)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.add(AbstractTreeViewer.java:160)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.add(CommonViewer.java:302)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.navigator.internal.ClearPlaceHolderJob.runInUIThread(ClearPlaceHolderJob.java:42)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.ClearJeePlaceHolderJob.runInUIThread(ClearJeePlaceHolderJob.java:32)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4211)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3827)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

Is this a bug in eclipse or lucene? I found other topics about this plubing but it didn't help me a lot. Of course i tried things like cleaning the project etc. Does anyone know how i can solve this? I am in badly need to continue my development of my lucene app.

Comment: Looks like Eclipse bug [442762](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442762)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like this problem was the consequence of another problem in my project: Eclipse could not load the project descriptor, because the web.xml had an error. Since i fixed this the other error is also gone.